# Array.sort doesn't work properly when called twice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've been playing this for a while. Why is val_a changed when I run the function to sort val b? How can I get around this? When I run the function separately they work, but when I run them together something goes wrong somewhere.

```js
var GLOBALS = {"items":[]};
var val_a;
var val_b;
GLOBALS.items=[
{"thing":"one","val_a":0.5,"val_b":0.2},
{"thing":"two","val_a":0.2,"val_b":0.3},
{"thing":"three","val_a":0.3,"val_b":0.1}];


 val_a = GLOBALS.items.sort(function (a, b) {
  a=parseFloat(a.val_a);
  b=parseFloat(b.val_a);

  if (a < b) {
   return -1;
  }
  if (a > b) {
   return 1;
  }
  return 0;
 });

 val_b = GLOBALS.items.sort(function (a, b) {
  a=parseFloat(a.val_b);
  b=parseFloat(b.val_b);

  if (a < b) {
   return -1;
  }
  if (a > b) {
   return 1;
  }
  return 0;
 });


 console.log("val_a",val_a);
 console.log("val_b",val_b);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're seeing what you're seeing is that `val_a` and `val_b` just contain references to the same array, which is also referenced from `GLOBALS.items`. `sort` changes the state of the array that all three of those variables are pointing to.

Variables contain values, not objects. When dealing with objects (including arrays), the value in the variable is a *reference* to the object, which actually exists elsewhere in memory. Think of that reference as a number telling the JavaScript engine where the object is elsewhere in memory. (More below.)

If you want three separate arrays (the original `items`, then a copy sorted by `val_a`, and another sorted by `val_b`), you want to make a shallow copy of the array before sorting it, which you can do with `slice`:

```
val_a = GLOBALS.items.slice().sort(...);
```

---

About the array being elsewhere in memory, here's a simpler example:

```
var a = [42]; // A variable with a reference to an array, which is
              // elsewhere in memory
```

That gives us this in memory:

```
                    +---------+
a<REF5512>--------->| (array) |
                    +---------+
                    | 0: 42   |
                    +---------+
```

(That `REF5512` is just completely made up to make the point that a reference is a value. We never see the raw reference values.)

Then if we do:

```
var b = a;    // A copy of that same reference
```

That gives us this in memory:

```
a<REF5512>---+
             |      +---------+
             +----->| (array) |
             |      +---------+
b<REF5512>---+      | 0: 42   |
                    +---------+
```

If we change the state of the array (for instance, by sorting it), naturally that change is visible from either variable, as they're both referring to the same array:

```
b[0] = 67;
```

gives us

```
a<REF5512>---+
             |      +---------+
             +----->| (array) |
             |      +---------+
b<REF5512>---+      | 0: 67   | State of the array changed
                    +---------+
```

`slice` creates a *new* array with a copy of the values in the old array (just the values; the *objects* in your array aren't copied). So for instance:

```
b = a.slice();
```

Gives us:

```
                    +---------+
a<REF5512>--------->| (array) |
                    +---------+
                    | 0: 67   |
                    +---------+

                    +---------+
b<REF7341>--------->| (array) |
                    +---------+
                    | 0: 67   |
                    +---------+
```

Note how the reference in `b` is no longer the same as in `a`.

---

Side note: Your `sort` callbacks can be much simpler:

```
val_a = GLOBALS.items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.val_a) - parseFloat(b.val_a);
});
```

The `sort` callback just has to return a value less than zero (it doesn't have to be specifically -1), greater than zero (it doesn't have to be specifically 1), or equal to zero.

Comment: There should be a badge just for you, called "The Flash: providing a correct answer in less than 15 seconds".

Comment: For now I'm using this (if anyone ever runs into the same problem) but I want to understand what's going on.
'
    function quicksort(data,key) {
        if (data.length == 0) return [];
  
        var left = [], right = [], pivot = data[0];
 
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(data[i][key] < pivot[key])
                left.push(data[i])
            else
                right.push(data[i]);
        }
  
        return quicksort(left,key).concat(pivot, quicksort(right));
    }'

Comment: @TeeraMusic: You don't have to implement your own sort (although of course you can), as I said above, if you want separate arrays, just use `slice` to create a copy. That `quicksort` is creating copies (multiple) of the array.