# sorting computed values and updating computed values vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

In my vue app, I get some JSON from my API, I am then computing that returned data and sorting it via one of it's attributes, I am then wanting to then resort it every time that attribute is updated on the client side, I thought it would be enough to add `v-model="tag.weight" to the input but apparently not? What am I doing incorrectly?

```
<div class="mt-6" v-if="this.sortedTags">
        <div class="w-full flex justify-between pb-2 border-white">
            <div class="w-1/3 p-4 font-black">Tag</div>
            <div class="p-4 font-black">Active</div>
            <div class="p-4 font-black">Weight</div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-full flex justify-between" v-for="tag in this.sortedTags" :key="tag.id">
            <div class="w-1/3 p-4">{{ tag.tag }}</div>
            <div class="p-4"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
            <div class="p-4"><input type="text" v-model="tag.weight" size="3" class="text-black"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>


computed: {
    ...mapState(['admin']),
    sortedTags() {
        return this.admin.tags.sort(function(a, b) {
            a.weight - b.weight;
        });
    }
}
```

What I was hoping for what the 1) if entered a number into the weight field that is bound `tag.weight` it would order it based on that input, and 2) When I add new object to the data, it would resort it.

Comment: *resort it every time that attribute is updated* What do you mean by attribute here? Which element should invoke the resort function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got similar result when omitting the `return`, it will give you response, but re-sorting won't work.
Therefore, just use `return a.weight - b.weight;` instead of a simple `a.weight - b.weight;`

Detailed explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38159151/3256489

Comment: Or turn it into an arrow function , `return this.admin.tags.sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight);`

Comment: I did as outlined by @4givN but it seemed to double the amount of objects in the array?